# g++: was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, g++

I have thoroughly searched for a similar thread on SO but found nothing. Searching for "was not declared in this scope" yields a lot of results but I think this is different.

Basically, the following line (in a CertainClass.cpp file):

```
Archivo* arc;
```

Generates:

```
error: ‘arc’ was not declared in this scope
```

Choosing a different variable name makes no difference. The Archivo class is included.

If I attempt to define a pointer like that inside the CertainClass.h file, it compiles without problems.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Please construct a minimal test-case.

Comment: Sort of sounds like a circular include.

Comment: is that the only error message you get?

Comment: Looks likely that there's some mistake above, like a missing ;.

Comment: I will look into circular includes. I have to say that removing the line makes the compilation finish successfully. I am not sure whether I can make a minimal test case, I will have to dig a bit more. Thanks for answering !

Comment: I suspect that `Archivo` is declared as something other than a class so it's treating the `*` as an operator rather than part of a pointer declaration.  Keep in mind that a macro named `Archivo` might be playing a role in making what's going on non-obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that you haven't defined a class instance or other object also called Archivo. For example, the following fails:

```
class Foo {
} Foo;

int main() {
    Foo* boo;
}
```

The error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5: error: ‘boo’ was not declared in this scope
```

The error occurs because `*` is interpreted as the `*` operation between an object called `Foo` and an object called `boo`.

To see if this is really your error, try writing

```
class Archivo *arc;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `Archivo` type isn't available at global scope in the source file. You can use `g++ -E` to pre-process the file and then analyze that to find out why it's not defined or is out of scope.